# How to get a first td values of every table using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all first `td` values using **JQuery**.

Here is my code:

```
<tr id="#ASPxGridView1_DXHeadersRow0">
    <td id="ASPxGridView1_col0" class="dxgvHeader" onmousedown="ASPx.GHeaderMouseDown('ASPxGridView1', this, event);" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;">
       <table style="width:100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>

    <td id="ASPxGridView1_col1" class="dxgvHeader" onmousedown="ASPx.GHeaderMouseDown('ASPxGridView1', this, event);" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;">
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Worksheet ID</td>
                    <td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
     </td>
</tr>
```

I want to get only 2 td (Status.Worksheet ID) elements from my above code using JQuery

Comment: @JoeLissner when I add your code in alert, it's showing object,object

Comment: Do you want the first td in the table, or the first td in each row of the table?

Comment: Or do all your tables only have 1 row?

Comment: @Barmar no I have so many rows. I tried in this way `$(".dxgvHeader td:first-child").text()`. this code is working. but I want to seperate by comma. How can I separate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any valid CSS selector to JQuery, so all you need is:

```
$("td:first-child");
```

```js
// This will find and group together all the `<td>` elements that are the first ones
// within their parent (<tr>).
var $results = $("td:first-child");

// You can loop over the set and work with the individual DOM elements...
$results.each(function(index, result){
  // result is the DOM element we're looping over
  console.log(result.textContent);
});

// Or, you can access a specific element by index:
console.log($results[0].textContent + ", " + $results[1].textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr id="#ASPxGridView1_DXHeadersRow0">
    <td id="ASPxGridView1_col0" class="dxgvHeader" onmousedown="ASPx.GHeaderMouseDown('ASPxGridView1', this, event);" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;"><table style="width:100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>

    <td id="ASPxGridView1_col1" class="dxgvHeader" onmousedown="ASPx.GHeaderMouseDown('ASPxGridView1', this, event);" style="border-top-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;">
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Worksheet ID</td>
                    <td style="width:1px;text-align:right;"><span class="dx-vam">&nbsp;</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @mohamedfaiz  The `$()` is how you access the JQuery object. The string passed to it is the query.

Comment: This only returns the first `td` in the DOM, not the first `td` in each table.

Comment: @Barmar Yup. Updated answer. Both are returned now.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i tried this code `alert($('.dxgvHeader').find('td:first-child').first());`. It returns `[object object]`

Comment: `:first-child` will return the first TD in every row, not the first TD in the table.

Comment: Could you change your `console.log()` so it doesn't try to print so much in the SO console emulator?

Comment: @Barmar The OP is not asking for the first `td` in the table. My code returns exactly what the OP is asking for. You only need to see the first 4 lines of the returned code to see what the wrapped set contains. Don't worry about the rest.

Comment: The example he posted happens to have only 1 row, so first in table is the same as first in every row. It won't work with a different example.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I tried this code `alert($(".dxgvHeader td:first-child").text());` It's working fine. But it's completely mess up. I want to separate by comma(,)

Comment: @mohamedfaiz That's because the result of the query is a set of the matched elements. To get their values individually, you must either loop over the set (which I've updated my answer to do) or specifically extract the data from one of the elements in the set (you can use JQuery's `get()` for this or append a simple index to the set).

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you scott. Thank you for your explaination